# Bulk/batch UPDATE on Postgres table is considerable slow

Tags: python, database, postgresql, amazon-rds, psycopg2

Currently I am using psycopg2 to bulk update a column on a postgres table from a pandas dataframe. While testing local postgres instance on docker takes less than one minute to update 100k rows but the same script on prod takes more than 60 minutes to update. For the same prod DB bulk INSERT for the same 100k rows takes less than a minute. What parameters could I modify on my prod DB to make the bulk UPDATEs as fast as on local? Table is indexed on ID which is used on the WHERE condition.

```
def write_to_db(data: pd.DataFrame, ID):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            query="""
            UPDATE table SET column_1=%s WHERE id=%s AND name=%s
            """
            argslist = [(row['column_1'], Dd, index) for index, row in data.iterrows()]
            execute_batch(cur, query, argslist)
        conn.commit()
        logger.info("successfully updated to the DB")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("error in writing to the DB: ", e)
        conn.rollback()
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

So far I have increased the size of the DB on AWS RDS from t3.micro to t3.xlarge which increases the RAM from 1 GB to 8 GB but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Why do you think it's an issue with RAM? In most cloud environments almost all performance issues are related to disk, to IO. The lack of IO. Please your environment, CPU, RAM and IO. And as always, a single table or row lock can stop your entire proces, check for this as well

Comment: Is the indexed column the corresponding datarype to the parameter being passed?

Comment: 1) `execute_batch` has a `page_size` argument which by default is set to 100. I would increase that, starting with say 1000. 2) Where is `Dd` coming from? Also how is `index` related to the column `name`? 3) Is this script on the Postgres server or remotely? 4) Where are you measuring the time?